# How do I limit 4 records for every record selected in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do I select the **x** records of a Mysql query that are defined by dates, that is, I need to make payment only for the 4 most paid days (if person has worked for 4 or more than 4 days in a month) or all the days if person has worked for 4 days or less in the month..

| Date | Employee | Pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23-01-01 | x | 100 |
| 23-01-01 | y | 100 |
| 23-01-01 | z | 200 |
| 23-01-02 | x | 300 |
| 23-01-02 | y | 100 |
| 23-01-02 | z | 200 |
| 23-01-03 | x | 500 |
| 23-01-03 | y | 500 |
| 23-01-03 | z | 500 |
| 23-01-05 | x | 700 |
| 23-01-05 | y | 800 |
| 23-01-05 | z | 900 |
| 23-01-07 | x | 800 |
| 23-01-07 | y | 800 |
| 23-01-07 | z | 500 |
| 23-01-09 | x | 50 |
| 23-01-09 | y | 60 |
| 23-01-09 | z | 50 |
| 23-11-10 | x | 300 |
| 23-11-10 | y | 200 |
| 23-11-10 | z | 100 |
| 23-11-11 | x | 300 |
| 23-11-11 | y | 200 |
| 23-11-11 | z | 100 |
| 23-11-20 | x | 200 |
| 23-11-20 | y | 200 |
| 23-11-20 | z | 300 |
| 23-05-22 | x | 200 |
| 23-05-22 | y | 200 |
| 23-05-22 | z | 200 |

If I select with a where date is may, i want a result like:

| Date | Employee | Pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23-05-22 | x | 200 |
| 23-05-22 | y | 200 |
| 23-05-22 | z | 200 |

if January

| Date | Employee | Pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23-01-02 | x | 300 |
| 23-01-02 | y | 100 |
| 23-01-02 | z | 200 |
| 23-01-03 | x | 500 |
| 23-01-03 | y | 500 |
| 23-01-03 | z | 500 |
| 23-01-05 | x | 700 |
| 23-01-05 | y | 800 |
| 23-01-05 | z | 900 |
| 23-01-07 | x | 800 |
| 23-01-07 | y | 800 |
| 23-01-07 | z | 500 |

Comment: may is a month not a date, anf please show your attempts

Comment: In my Java code, I have added a way to Identify month and set minimum and maximum dates, like **between 2023-01-01 and 2023-01-31, 2020-02-01 and 2020-02-29, 2021-02-01 and 2021-02-28**

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_, not records.

Answer (score 0):

With Mysql 8 you can use a combination of ROW_NUMBER and a CTE to get the wanted data

To get the right data, you should read up on [date function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

also tables have rows and columns, if  you want to learn sql, you should use the common language

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
`Date`, `Employee`, `Pay`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY `Employee` ORDER BY `Date` ASC) rn
  FROM Table1
  WHERE MONTH(`Date`) = 5)
SELECT `Date`, `Employee`, `Pay`
  FROM CTE WHERE rn <= 4
```

| Date | Employee | Pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23-05-22 | x | 200 |
| 23-05-22 | y | 200 |
| 23-05-22 | z | 200 |

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
`Date`, `Employee`, `Pay`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY `Employee` ORDER BY `Date` ASC) rn
  FROM Table1
  WHERE MONTH(`Date`) = 1)
SELECT `Date`, `Employee`, `Pay`
  FROM CTE WHERE rn <= 4
```

| Date | Employee | Pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23-01-01 | x | 100 |
| 23-01-02 | x | 300 |
| 23-01-03 | x | 500 |
| 23-01-05 | x | 700 |
| 23-01-01 | y | 100 |
| 23-01-02 | y | 100 |
| 23-01-03 | y | 500 |
| 23-01-05 | y | 800 |
| 23-01-01 | z | 200 |
| 23-01-02 | z | 200 |
| 23-01-03 | z | 500 |
| 23-01-05 | z | 900 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a1RKZL_g)